# Signifigance of a url with an empty query string and a fragment identifier

Tags: url

I'm encountering URL's of the form `http://foobar.com/something?#foo/bar.html` which I'm interpreting as an empty query string followed by the fragment identifier "foo/bar.html" (am I parsing that correctly?)

I'm not familiar with this pattern; what's the significance of the empty query string?  Is it necessary?

(some empirical testing suggests that the site serving these url's behaves identically whether the '?' character is present or not, but still I wonder if I'm missing something.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider two URIs:

1. `http://example.com/`
2. `http://example.com/?`

By the [URI standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.3) these two http scheme URIs are not equivalent: "Normalization should not remove delimiters when their associated component is empty unless licensed to do so by the scheme specification.  For example, the URI "http://example.com/?" cannot be assumed to be equivalent to any of the examples above." This means HTTP servers are allowed to return different content for the two different URIs.

However, in practice most HTTP servers don't return different content when an empty string query is included.

When I've seen a URI with an empty query on the web its just an artifact of an HTML page using a relative URI to navigate to the current page but removing the content of the query. For example `http://example.com/a/b/c?d=e&f=g` could have a link to the relative URI `?` which will navigate to `http://example.com/a/b/c?`.